# RSA Ciphertext Message.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

Hey I'm really stuck and I have to finish soon.

Part A

Ray, Sam and Todd are lazy, and they have set up their RSA public keys as $(3,nR),(3,nS),(3,nT)$ respectively. We may assume that any two of $nR,nS,nT$ are coprime. Zach encrypted a message $M$ using each of the three keys, producing the ciphertexts $CR,CS,CT$ for Ray, Sam and Todd respectively. Note that we must have:
$0 ≤ M ≤ \mathrm{min} \{nR,nS,nT\}$

Prove that if one obtains the values of $CR,CS,CT$,then the message $M$ can be determined.

Part B

Suppose $nR = 7729,nS = 8023,nT = 8383$, and you have found out that $CR = 2553,CS = 5337,CT = 4156$. Use what you have learned from part (a) to solve for $M$. (Do not factor the public keys, show the set up of the calculations and the results.)

Comment: Given that $n$ divides each of $nR,nS,nT$, we get $n=1$. Maybe we assume $R,S,T$ are coprime?

Comment: How did we get n divides nR,nS,nT?

Comment: Does $nR$ not mean $n\cdot R$?

Comment: @user136088 if $R$ is an integer, then $\frac{nR}{n}=R$ which as we just said was an integer. Likewise for the rest.

Comment: Im not sure but if nR means n*R does that make it easier?

Comment: It makes n=1, which seems weird, because then why write n?

Answer (score 0):

As the comments show, your notation is slightly suboptimal; I will use a more standard one.

Part A: Because the $N_k$ are pair-wise coprime it follows from the Chinese Remainder Theorem that 
$$C_R \equiv M^3 \pmod {N_R}$$
$$C_S \equiv M^3 \pmod {N_S}$$
$$C_T \equiv M^3 \pmod {N_T}$$
has a solution $C$ with $C \equiv M^3 \pmod {N_R N_S N_T}$.
Since $M<N_k\;$ we have $M^3 < N_R N_S N_T\;$ and can we compute $M = C^{\frac{1}{3}}\;$ without modular arithmetic.

Part B: With the given values solve the CRT system

```
x=2553 mod 7729
x=5337 mod 8023
x=4156 mod 8383
```

and get $x=C=2460375\;$ and $M=C^{\frac{1}{3}} = 135.\;$ It is easy to check that

```
135^3 mod 7729 = 2553
135^3 mod 8023 = 5337
135^3 mod 8383 = 4156
```

Note that this is a simple case of [Hastad's Broadcast Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%27s_Attack#H.C3.A5stad.27s_Broadcast_Attack) on plain RSA.